# Crystal IF Next in fomula

Tags: crystal-reports

I have learned Crystal by trial and error, so please forgive my phrasing.

I want to combine text and fields.  If there is more than one instance of Tensile.SOItemNum, then I want to repeat all instances of that field within my resultant text string and have the multiple instances be separated by commas.  (Actually I would want this section to repeat for each record of Tensile.SOITEM.

The following is the formula for one text string and this would work if there were just one record.

```
    Formula = "0003015339|01|" & totext({Tensile.SONum},0,"") & "-" & 
totext({Tensile.SOItemNum},0,"") & "-" & {Tensile.Lot} & "|" & {SOItem.CustPO} & 
"|" & totext({SOItem.SOItemNum},0,"") & "|" & {SOItem.ProdCode} & "|" & 
totext({ManifestLotView.Manifest},0,"") & "-" & 
totext({ManifestLotView.SONum},0,"") & "-" & 
totext({ManifestLotView.SOItemNum},0,"")
```

Which produces:

```
0003015339|01|114667-10-1-B-1|5400361554-R01|10|XALRET05012|27202-114667-10
```

If there were a 114667-10-1-B-1 and a 114668-5-2-B-1, I would want the string resultant string to read:

```
0003015339|01|114667-10-1-B-1,114668-5-2-B-1|5400361554-
R01|10|XALRET05012|27202-114667-10
```

This is some of what I was trying, but it is not a valid formula.  I have not used the Next function before.

```
Formula = "0003015339|01|" & totext({Tensile.SONum},0,"") & "-" & 
totext({Tensile.SOItemNum},0,"") & "-" & {Tensile.Lot} & IF nextvalue 
({Tensile.SONum}) > 1 then   "," & totext({Tensile.SONum},0,"") & "-" & 
totext({Tensile.SOItemNum},0,"") & "-" & {Tensile.Lot} end if   "|" & 
{SOItem.CustPO} & "|" & totext({SOItem.SOItemNum},0,"") & "|" & 
{SOItem.ProdCode} & "|" & totext({ManifestLotView.Manifest},0,"") & "-" & 
totext({ManifestLotView.SONum},0,"") & "-" & 
totext({ManifestLotView.SOItemNum},0,"")
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Isn't it "next()" instead of "nextvalue()"?

Comment: Thanks heringer.  Yes, it should be "next".  I made some changes and am now using:

Comment: if next({Tensile.SONum}) <>0 
then  ("," & totext (next({Tensile.SONum}) ,0,"")  & "-" & totext (next({Tensile.SOItemNum}),0,"") & "-" & next({Tensile.Lot})&  
if next({Tensile.SONum}) <>0 then ("," & totext (next({Tensile.SONum}) ,0,"") & "-" & totext (next({Tensile.SOItemNum}),0,"") & 
"-" & next({Tensile.Lot})& if next({Tensile.SONum}) <>0 then  ("," &  totext (next({Tensile.SONum}) ,0,"")
 & "-" & totext (next({Tensile.SOItemNum}),0,"") & "-" & next({Tensile.Lot})

Comment: This is closer to what I want, but I am still not getting the intended results.  I get repeated values and some skipped values.